# how to hide an element before applying data bind

Tags: angularjs

I want to hide a text message while the js is loading and data binding is not yet applied. I have tried something like this but its always hiding the message

```
.hide { display: none; }
<div class="hide" ng-hide="haveRecords">No Records found</div>
```

If I remove the class hide from div. then this element is shown for some milli-seconds before the data binding is applied. How to fix it?

Answer (score 6):

This is what **[`ngCloak`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)** is for.
You can use it like this:

```
<head>
    ...
    <style>[ng-cloak] {display: none !important;}</style>
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <div ng-cloak ng-hide="haveRecords">No Records found</div>
```

NOTE: The style in the head is only required if you include the AngularJS script at the end of body (which is a good idea anyway).

Comment: data binding is not yet activated then how ng-cloak will work? Its still showing the div for me

Comment: I had a typo in my `<style>` rule. Try it again. You can read all about `ngCloak` in the docs (see link in my answer). All it doesis hide an element until Angular is loaded, does its magic and removes the `ng-cloak`.

Comment: @coure2011: Have you tried the proposed solution ? Did it work for you ?

Comment: Its not working. I fixed it something like this... .hide {display: none; } .show{display: block !important; } and then <div class="hide" ng-class="{'show' : !haveRecords}"></div>

Answer (score 1):

You should use [ngCloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

> The `ngCloak` directive is used to prevent the Angular html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.

*Code*

```
<div ng-hide="haveRecords" ng-cloak>No Records found</div>
```

Comment: Nope... it still shows the message No Records for few milli seconds

Comment: @coure2011, Try with adding Css `[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}`

Comment: still not helpful, I also try to add class .ng-cloak, and set a debugger point at first line of Controller.. I found that its removing .ng-cloak class before loading the controller...